# buttonText on 'today' view not updating

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I'm updating the buttonText for 'today' in views and its not working.

Updating the buttonText for the other buttons works fine.

```
fullcalendar: {
    firstHour: 9,
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'listDay,listWeek,month,listMonth,'
    },
    slotMinutes: 30,
    theme:false,
    views: {
        today: {buttonText: 'Today'},
        listWeek: {buttonText: 'Week'},
        listDay: {buttonText: 'Day'},
        listMonth: {buttonText: 'List'},
        month: {buttonText: 'Month'}
    },
    defaultView: 'month'
},
```

'today' should be capitalized but its not...

Comment: can you please show more code and explain more what do you trying to reach ?

Comment: @G.aziz I see no issue with what's been provided. What more do you want to know? If you are familiar with fullCalendar the question should be fairly clear.

Comment: my fault i didn't check the tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's demo using your code: http://jsfiddle.net/ocvpsLgt/ . The "today" button you're seeing is the one defined in the `left` area of the header settings. It's a [standard navigation button](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/header) defined by fullCalendar which changes the date to the current today. It has nothing to do with the custom view you tried to define which you named as `today`.

You can't define a view which has the same name as a standard navigation button - if you put that name into the header, fullCalendar will just think you are referring to the standard button, and display that. In any case, it makes no sense to define a view called "Today" - a view describes the layout of the calendar, not a particular date. Today's date can be reached from any type of view. You've already got "listDay" which will cover a single day - any day, including today. I can't see why you'd want another day view, unless it was a different type, such as "agendaDay".

If you just want to capitalise the name of the standard "today" button, then that can be done via the global [buttonText](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/buttonText) setting:

```
buttonText: { today: "Today" }
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ocvpsLgt/1/

Answer (score 0):

Heres for lists as well

buttonText :

{

today: 'Today',

month: 'Month',

week: 'Week',

day: 'Day',

listMonth: 'List Month',

listYear: 'List Year',

listWeek: 'List Week,

listDay: 'List Day'

}

here->https://fullcalendar.io/docs/buttonText